# update/dropping external table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm working on Hive (tables) and I have some problem with updating and dropping external table.
I created 2 external tables : T1 and T2 with same attributes

```
create external table T1(
nom string,
prenom string,
age int);
```

With query :

```
insert overwrite table T2( 
select
nom,
prenom,
age from T1;
```

I can update T2 with data in T1, but doing :

```
drop table T2;
```

and then recreating it `create external table T2.....` I get automatically all present in T2 before dropping, while I would to have an empty table.
Is it "normal". Anybody could explain to me, why? and/or recommandate some method?

thx.

Comment: You see, if you use `external` keyword, it's mean that data will be not removed if table will be dropped. You can create second table without this keyword

Comment: Hi James, is it possible to do : insert overwrite column col1...?  instead of : insert overwrite table T1....?? i neeed it to update just one column of a table. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the table would not have removed the data present in the HDFS. The files will be available in the folder

```
/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/tablename
```

Try creating the table second time by removing the data from HDFS  or with some other location specified in the create query itself.